# Find pattern and add between array if keyword is found

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a PHP configuration file that I would like to change via script. The configuration file contains several blocks that require me to change them. A block contains the following:

```
'KEYWORD1' =>
  array (
    Random text here
  ),
```

Several blocks:

```
'KEYWORD2' =>
  array (
    Random text here
  ),
```

What I would like to know if it's possible is to add between the `array`. Depending on the `KEYWORD` to add certain text.

An example output of the script would be:

```
'KEYWORD2' =>
  array (
    'enable' => true,
    'email' => false,
  ),
```

Ideally, I would be able to find the keyword and add the text only if it matches. For example: Search for `KEYWORD1` and add certain configurations as the one in the block above.

Any tips? Ideas?

Comment: You can write `php` console script and handle this info over **serialize/unserialize** functions. Do you need do this only via bash?

Comment: Can you show the complete array ? Please edit your post

Answer (score 0):

I Tested for KEYWORD2 and it worked fine You can  add keyword in loop where  and you want change

```
for i in KEYWORD2
do
sed -n  '/'$i'/,/),/p' l.txt|sed "s/array.*/&\n'enable' => true,\n'email' => false,/g"| sed '/Random/d'
done
```

Output

```
'KEYWORD2' =>
  array (
'enable' => true,
'email' => false,
  ),
```

============================================================
Suppose you want to change for both keyword1  and keyword2

use below code

```
for i in KEYWORD1 KEYWORD2;
 do
sed -n  '/'$i'/,/),/p' l.txt|sed "s/array.*/&\n'enable' => true,\n'email' => false,/g"| sed '/Random/d'
done
```